# WIFI doesn't have a valid IP configuration

Tags: windows-10

My new PC, which I got only 3 weeks ago and has normally worked well with mobile hotspots, started giving the "connected, no internet" message when connected to any of them.

I ran the troubleshooter and got "WIFI doesn't have a valid IP configuration". Running the common 7-9 fixes via answers.microsoft and other sources didn't work.

I got fed up and reset the PC and everything was fine again. I wasn't going to take any chances so I installed all the new Windows 10 updates. Thought I was in the clear, but now the problem is back. "Connected, no internet".

What's the best solution to this problem?

Update 7th, July, '18: reset my PC again and this time painstakingly noted every single action I took. Problem resurfaced again after installing a particular network monitoring tool. Reset PC yet again this time decided not to install the said monitoring tool. PC's been working fine for over a week now.

Comment: Do you actually have no internet connection at that point or is it merely displayed?

Comment: @Seth I truly have no internet connection.

Comment: If you believe you have found the answer, you can answer your own question and state what the "particular network monitoring tool" is that is causing the issue, it may help others in the future.